# Open a web page from anywhere with a single action

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity, launcher

I'm using the same webapps over and over.

I have the following things in place:

- shortcuts on my desktop --> I need to go back to the desktop and click. Then all is minimized.
- favorite in my browser --> I need to switch to the browser, locate the fav and click
- a special 'new tab' page with shortcuts --> same than before with an extra step (new tab)

I autoclose browsers tabs to avoid memory inflation, so those webapp are often closed. I also need to have many tabs open for the same app, so even with an open page I often need to open a new one.

I would like to open a new tab for these webapps in a single action, or a 2 steps action that does not break my current windows layout as the 'windows + d' do ?

Ideally I would like to have a kind of alt-tab, that pops my desktop icons on top of everything and disappear once an app has been launched.

I'm using other softwares that use plenty of keyboard shortcuts, so the solution must not interfere with my current eco-system.

My shorcut bar is already full, so this is not what I want to use.

What would be a solution for my need ?

*Some precisions about my environment:*

- I have installed fences, so my icons are well organized, in the desktop.
- I have a 3 widescreens setup, so I would like to have something that pop under my mouse, not far away.
- I have also already tried various launcher/dock but they are often half-backed, intrusive, not supported, ugly, buggy... or require you to type a lot. I probably have missed a good one but I'm bored to mess my system. It is hard to give you all the names.

For example http://sourceforge.net/projects/circledock/ is a good example of what I'm looking for:
simple shortcut to bring the thing to the front, then click to open a program and it is gone.

If I could have something that is not in version alpha since 2012, that does not trash my explorer and that can use my desktop icons (my fences group would be even better), that is simple and not awful to look at, I would probably pay for it :)

About AutoHotKey, I have used it once for another need, but I remember it like a complex system.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot on your screen. You've given us all the "wants" and "don't wants", but what have you tried? Have you looked at adding a toolbar to the taskbar? Custom sidebar gadget?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but you could use AutoHotKey to do the thing you said in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is this:

- Create a batch file to open multiple tabs of a browser to particular websites.
- Create a shortcut to the batch file.
- Create a keyboard shortcut for the shortcut. (Right-click on the file and select Properties.)

Now you can press ctrl-alt-[Your-favorite-letter] to launch all of your browsers. You should be able to set an option in the browser of your choice to have them all open in the same window in different tabs. [This question discusses how to do it in IE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188850/how-to-launch-multiple-internet-explorer-windows-tabs-from-batch-file) You can do the same thing for Chrome and Firefox as well.

Comment: This is a good barebone solution that does not require extra tools.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Run?

Windows Key + R, then http(s)://websiteyouwant.com

With Firefox running, it opened a new tab at the site I wanted. I think it also memorizes what you put in, so you won't have to type the full URL multiple times.

Comment: It is a lot to type, I really want to have something snappy.